# Where to find HTML to post Adsense Code

Tags: html, adsense

I am a **beginner** WP user and having an issue of where to find HTML area to post AdSense code.  I know that AdSense directs it to be posted between  &  tags, but I am not even sure where this is located.

I am using a plugin, AdInserter, but not sure if that is the location to add AdSense code either.

Probably an elementary question, but like mentioned I am a beginner!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ads are most commonly displayed in the sidebar. You can add Google Adsense in your sidebar by using WordPress widgets. Simply go to Appearance » Widgets page in your WordPress admin area. Next, drag & drop the 'Custom HTML' widget to the appropriate widget area and paste your Google AdSense code in there.

Comment: Please mark my reply above as correct answer, so other people know if this was helpful.